# Transactional outbox and inbox with optimistic concurrency control

Tags: sql-server, masstransit

is it possible to configure MassTransit transactional outbox and inbox with optimistic concurrency control instead of locks? In my database I have transactions with optimistic concurrency control and I want send messages to be saved as part of this transaction - how can I do that? I suppose I cannot have in the same transaction both locks and optimistic conccurency? I'm using mssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locks are required to ensure exactly once consumer semantics. The Transactional Outbox was designed with this in mind, and therefore requires it.

Comment: So in order to use transactional outbox in masstransit I need to change design of the rest of code to adjust to locking strategy? It doesn't seem right, as optimistic conccurency is a hard requirement in my case

Comment: I think I was fairly clear, if that doesn't meet your requirements then it doesn't sound like you'll be using it. You can always write your own.

Comment: Yes that is fair statement from your side and I accept it. Just wish masstransit will support that in the future